# Зачем super в методах? Android

Tags: java, android

Часто встречаю код, примерно как этот:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.add:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

И во всех них имеется строка `super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);`. Как я понимаю, это вызывается метод суперкласса, только зачем он? Удалял эту строку, все работает.

Comment: работает, если вся цепочка `super` состоит из пустых методов, или Вы чего-то не замечаете

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это делается для того чтобы если в суперклассе уже есть реализация этого метода, она вызвалась и сделала всё что ей нужно. Конкретно в данном случае метод суперкласса видимо ничего не выполняет поэтому поведение программы не меняется.